# Show animated content not only when you scroll but also when you enter the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Do you know when you scroll down a website and the content appears gradually from top, bottom, left or right? The problem I have is when you enter the website, let's say you want to animate a big title in the header and you still didn't scroll, so this title won't appear but I want it to appear without having to wait the user to scroll.

The content I have for the scrolling funcion is this one:

```
window.onscroll = function(){

    let elements = $('.scroll-content');
    let screenSize = window.innerHeight;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];

        if(element.getBoundingClientRect().top < screenSize) {
            element.classList.add('visible');
        }
    }
  }
```

The rest is done with styles on css. Of course this only works for scrolling so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Start with the big title hidden in the HTML-file you write and and ID assigned to the element. Then have a JS-function you trigger after the page is loaded. You can use the `window.onload` event handler for that [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). In that function use `getElementById` and add the `visible` class to it.

Comment: okay thank you, it kind of works similar to the scroll function but didn't know the window.onload property so I didn't know what to use here. Thanks